# Polynomial Division Under Certain Remainders

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial such that when $P(x)$ is divided by $x-17$, the remainder is $14$, and when $P(x)$ is divided by $x-13$, the remainder is $6$. What is the remainder when $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-13)(x-17)$?

Here was my process, that I'm not sure if it's right or not:

We can write $P(x)$ in the form of $$P(x)=Q(x)(x-17)(x-13)+cx+d$$

Thus, by the remainder theorem, we have a system of equations:

\begin{align*}
14c+d &=6,\\
6c+d &=14.
\end{align*}

Solving gets $c=-1, d=20.$

Thus, our remainder is $\boxed{-x+20}.$

Did I make any flaws during my process. Thanks in advance for helping. :)

Comment: Not following.  We know that $P(17)=14$, say, from which we deduce that $17c+d=14$.  Similarly, $13c+d=6$.  Not sure where your equations are coming from.

Comment: Wait, so we just solve that system of equations?

Comment: Note, by the way, that you can check your tentative answer (or indeed any linear polynomial): divide $-x+20$ itself by each of $x-17$ and $x-13$—do you get remainders of $14$ and $6$ respectively?

Comment: It also might be worth commenting: don't be fooled into believing, from the numbers chosen in the problem, that the polynomial remainder when dividing by $x-17$ must always be between $0$ and $17$ (and similarly for $13$); check the case $P(x) = x^2$ for example. Polynomial remainders have smaller _degree_, but the size and sign of their coefficients can be arbitrary (literally anything, as linear algebra tells us).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$P(x)=Q(x)(x-17)(x-13)+cx+d$$

Now, let $x=17$, then we have $$17c+d=14$$

If we let $x=13$, then we have

$$13c+d=6$$

Now solve for $c$ and $d$.

Subtract the two equations, we ahve $4c=8 \iff c=2$. Proceed on to solve for $d$ to get the remainder.

Comment: $c=2, d=-20.$ Our remainder is $2x-20$

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: as a check, $2x-20=2(x-17)+14=2(x-13)+6$

Comment: Thank you all. $+1$ $\checkmark$